# What is the convergence interval of the function when center is not 0?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The following answer is wrong

For $x^{\frac{5}{3}}$ when the expansion is centered at $a=1$ the singularity is $x = 0$. The length from the center $\{1,0\}$ to the singularity $\{0,0\}$ is $1$

The convergence interval then becomes $[1-1,1+1]=[0,2]$

How to find the correct answer?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! The interval should be open.

Comment: When plotting this I can see that the expansion definitly converges within an interval

Comment: *A priori*, an interval of convergence is open. What happens at the boundary has to be examined on a case-by-case basis. This being said, I don't see why there should be a singularity at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As Bernard wrote: The interval should be open. In your case it should be $(0,2)$. Otherwise, $0\in[0,2]$ and $0$ is the singularity!

Moreover you are using the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, but your domain is just $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R^2$. Hence, you have to argue inside of $\mathbb R$:

The singularity is at the point $0$ while the expansion is centered at $1$, so the length from the center $1$ to the singularity $0$ is $|1-0|=1$ *and so on ...*.

But you have to be careful. Normally you have to check the expansion series for the convergence interval. In this case you are right, but for $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ the expansion series centered at $0$ converges just on $(-1,1)$ while $f$ has no singularities on $\mathbb R$.